# Reducing space between title and pie chart, using R-base

Tags: r, visualization, pie-chart

I have created a pie chart and I realize that the title of the pie chart is further away from the pie chart. I want to ask how I can shorten the distance between the title and the chart, using base R.

```
pie(group3$count, labels = a, col = c("orange", "pink"), main= "The percentage of Fuel type, among Low Emission cluster", cex.main=1 )
legend("bottomright", legend = c("DIESEL/ELECTRIC", "PETROL/ELECTRIC"), fill=c("pink","orange"))
```

Output:
[image]
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could build the plot separately using `legend()` and `title()` and in title call `line = 0.6` or any value lower than 1 to move the title closer.

Also I  think you are mixing up the colours for either the fill or the legend. one has pink before orange, and the other orange before pink.

```r
automatic <- sum(mtcars$am) / nrow(mtcars)
manual <- 1 - automatic

df <- data.frame(count = c(automatic, manual))

a <- c("Automatic", "Manual")

pie(df$count, col = c("pink", "orange"))

legend(x = "bottomright", 
       legend = a,
       fill = c("pink", "orange"))

title(main = "TITLE", cex.main = 1)
title(main = "TITLE, BUT CLOSER", cex.main = 1, line = 0.6)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>